# Calculate exact area under curve in Java

Tags: java, math

Are there any methods which do that? I have an application where I need the area under the curve, and I am given the formula, so if I can do the integration on hand, I should be able to do it programatically? I can't find the name of the method I'm referring to, but this image demonstrates it: http://www.mathwords.com/a/a_assets/area%20under%20curve%20ex1work.gif

Edit: to everyone replying, I have already implemented rectangular, trapezoidal and Simpson's rule. However, they take like 10k+ stripes to be accurate, and should I not be able to find programatically the integrated version of a function? If not, there must be a bloody good reason for that.

Comment: The 'bloody good reason' is that it's often 'bloody hard'.

Comment: If someone ever did it before, we should be able to use his implementation and integration would be as short as "import xxx; xxx.integrate(fctn);", or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's very true. I'm not sure that someone has done this for Java. Perhaps another question

Comment: you simply can't find a general solution that is going to work 100% of the time and lead to the _exact_ result. the reason being is that you cannot integrate ever possible function in terms of elementary functions. ie try finding the are under sin(x^2). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%28x%5E2%29 you can't get it to a form that is not based on integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Numerical integration**
There are multiple methods, which can be used. For description, have a look in [Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=155#).
For Java there is Apace Commons library, which can be used. Integration routines are in [Numerical Analysis](http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/analysis.html) section.

**Symbolic integration**
Check out [jScience](http://jscience.org/). [Functions](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/function/package-summary.html#package_description) module "provides support for fairly simple symbolic math analysis (to solve algebraic equations, integrate, differentiate, calculate expressions, and so on)".
If type of function is given, it can be possible to integrate faster in that specific case than when using some standard library.

Comment: I realize this is 10 years old, but please reproduce within the answer. Links tend to break and the first one requires a vulnerable version of Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 1):

To compute it exactly, you would need a [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) library of some sort to perform symbolic manipulations. Such systems are rather complicated to implement, and I am not familiar with any high quality, open source libraries for Java. An alternative, though, assuming it meets your requirements, would be to estimate the area under the curve using the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). Depending on how accurate you require your result to be, you can vary the size of the subdivisions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Simpsons rule or the trapezium rule, because it could be excessively complicated to integrate every single type of graph.

Answer (score 0):

See [Numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) specifically numerical integration. How about using the [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numerical integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration), using some rule, like already mentioned Simpsons, Trapezoidal, or [Monte-Carlo simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration). It uses pseudo random generator.

You can try some libraries for symbolic integration, but I'm not sure that you can get symbolic representation of every integral.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple but efficient approach:

```
public static double area(DoubleFunction<Double> f, double start, double end, int intervals) {
  double deltaX = (end - start)/intervals;
  double area = 0.0;
  double effectiveStart = start + (deltaX / 2);
  for (int i=0; i<intervals; ++i) {
    area += f.apply(effectiveStart + (i * deltaX));
  }
  return deltaX * area;
}
```

This is a Riemann sum using the midpoint rule, which is a variation of the trapezoidal rule, except instead of calculating the area of a trapezoid, I use a rectangle from f(x) at the middle of the interval. This is faster and gives a better result. This is why my effective starting value of x is at the middle of the first interval. And by looping over an integer, I avoid any round-off problems.

I also improve performance by waiting till the end of the loop before multiplying by `deltaX`. I could have written the loop like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<intervals; ++i) {
  area += deltaX * f.apply(effectiveStart + (i * deltaX)); // this is x * y for each rectangle
}
```

But `deltaX` is constant, so it's faster to wait till the loop is finished.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most popular forms of numeric integration is the Runge-Kutta order 4 (RK4) technique. It's implementations is as follows:

```
double dx,  //step size 
       y ;  //initial value
for(i=0;i<number_of_iterations;i++){
    double k1=f(y);
    double k2=f(y+dx/2*k1);
    double k3=f(y+dx/2*k2);
    double k4=f(y+dx*k3);
    y+= dx/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);
}
```

and will converge much faster than  rectangle, trapezoids, and Simpson's rule. It is one of the more commonly used techniques for integration in physics simulations.

Comment: This makes no sense. When you say `k1=f(y)` you're using y as x. But when you say `y+=...` you're treating y as an accumulated area. Are you leaving out some steps here? A more complete function would be helpful.